# Search Nearby Lat/Long Query Radius by KM

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to search for points in circle area

```
SET @center = GeomFromText('POINT(10 10)'); 
SET @radius = 30; 
SET @bbox = CONCAT('POLYGON((', 
    X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, ',', 
    X(@center) + @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, ',', 
    X(@center) + @radius, ' ', Y(@center) + @radius, ',', 
    X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) + @radius, ',', 
    X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, '))' 
); 
SELECT name, AsText(location) 
FROM Points 
WHERE Intersects( location, GeomFromText(@bbox) ) 
AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(location) - X(@center)), 2) + 
         POW( ABS(Y(location) - Y(@center)), 2 )) < @radius;
```

I Take the radius from the user by KM so I want to convert it to use it in the query

Comment: These are Cartesian coordinates rather than lat/ long, correct? If they are lang/long you need to read about the Haversine or Spherical Cosine Law distance formula. What do you mean when you say you want to convert Kilometer to radius?

Comment: In the site I tack the location of the user and search in radius by KM

Comment: Maybe you can show some example data. `SQRT(dx*dx + dy*dy)` doesn't even come close to working correctly as a distance computaiton for latitude and longitude. Read this. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/